# Combine two observables inside pipe() chain

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, combinelatest

I'm using Rxjs, and I want to create an Observable from the following pattern (in order):

1. get params from paramMap$, then ...
2. based on the value of params, get both (getData():Observable, getCategories():Observables) together, then ....
3. from ([data, categories]) create the final object.

The code would look like:

```
//route = this.ActivatedRoute

let obs$ = route.paramMap.pipe(

// combineLatest() is not a pipable operator, so it shouldn't be used inside .pipe()
// also it doesn't accept a function,
// but this just to show you what I want to do.

combineLatest(params=>getData(params.id), params=>getCategories(params.id)),

map(([data, categories])=>{
//do some changes...
return {data,categories}
}
)
)
```

also where is the best place to put this code in Angular project:

- `constructor()` is not the best practice, because this is a long-running operation (actually it has to do API requests)
- `ngOnInit()` is not recommended, because in some point I have to change `this.params` which is used in the template

```
...
combineLatest(params=>
   getData(params.id).pipe(
        map(data=>{
            this.params.type=data.type; 
            return data
           })), 
   params=>getCategories(...) 
)
```

in template:

```
<div>{{params.type}}</div>
```

Comment: I didn't the second part of your question. > because in some point I should to change this.params whitch is used in the template, how does that affect doing this process in`ngOnInit()`

Comment: you cannot change a value used in the template after check completed, so moving this code to `ngOnInit` is not the best practice. @Ashish Ranjan

Comment: I do not believe checks would be done on `ngOnInit()`, by this time even the view is not created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For piping the Observable after you get params, you can use `switchMap` and return a `forkJoin()` from within it.

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(switchMap((params) => {
    return forkJoin(getData(params.id), getCategories(params.id));
}));
```

I believe, subscribing an Observable, doing API requests, all should ideally go to `ngOnInit()` unless you have some very specific requirement where you do not want these subscriptions when the component loads.

As far as `this.params` is concerned, you can assign `this.params` under either using a piped `tap()` or where you do a subscription for this Observable.